# Efficient distributed algorithm to merge sets with common elements

Tags: algorithm, scala, merge, distributed-computing, apache-flink

I'm working on a distributed implementation of MinHash LSH on Flink and as a last step, I need to merge some clusters, identified as sets of elements similar among them.

So I have a distributed collection of sets as an input and I need an algorithm to efficiently merge sets with common elements. Given the computational model of Flink, the algorithm may be iterative and not necessarily map-reduce like.

Here an example:

from `{{1{1,2}},{2,{2,3}},{3,{4,5},{4{1,27}}}}` the result should be `{1,2,3,27},{4,5}` because the set #1,#2 and #4 have at least one element in common.

Comment: So this is transitive? I.e. if A and B have a common element and B and C have a different common element, you want A union B union C in the result?

Comment: We behave as if it's transitive, yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea: Gelly, which is part of Flink, has a connected components finder. Make a graph with a node for each set element and edges connecting the elements of each set in the simplest possible manner, e.g. for {a, b, c, d, ...} add [a,b], [a,c], [a,d], [a,... . Now find the connected components. Their nodes give the sets you're looking for.

**Edit**
If you are worried about the performance impact of converting from sets to graphs and back (although this worry is premature optimization; you should try it), it would be simple enough to re-implement Gelly's token-pushing scheme over sets. Here's how this would work. You already have the tokens in your example: the set numbering. Let S[i] be set i shown in your example. E.g. S[1] = {1,2}. Let R be an inverse multimap that takes each set element to the set of sets it belongs to. E.g. R[2] = {1,2} in your example.  Let T[i] be the elements reachable from set i by transitive non-null intersection "links". Then compute:

```
T[i] = S[i] for all i // with no links at all, a set reaches its own elements
loop
  for all i, Tnew[i] = \union_{ x \in T[i] } S[R[x]]  // add new reachables
  exit if Tnew == T
  T = Tnew
end loop
```

When done, the distinct values of map T are the answer you want. The max number of iterations ought to be log |U| where U is the universe of set elements.

Comment: I thought about that and it would probably work, but Gelly is not yet mature but overall the conversion would be too expensive, I believe. I will try anyway because maybe it performs well enough.

Comment: @Chobeat Well, if you're looking for a distributed algorithm, something like what Gelly does is probably the best you can do. Immature is better than starting from scratch. nb: I changed the way of connecting set elements in the graph to get better performance from Gelly's algorithm.

Comment: @Chobeat Okay I transformed the Gelly algorithm backward into your problem in case you want to try that.

Comment: Tomorrow I will spend the day trying the suggestions proposed here, starting from your. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Okay, I tried Gelly and I think I will follow your suggestion to avoid early optimization. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, there might be better ways, but how about this:

- In a map-step you emit a key-value pair for each element inside each set like: `element -> other elements`
- In a reduce-step you collect those other-elements and discard duplicates
- Repeat until the data structure stops changing

After the first iteration your data would look like this:

```
1 -> 2, 27
2 -> 1,3
3 -> 2
4 -> 5
5 -> 4
27 -> 1
```

After the second:

```
1 -> 2, 3, 27
2 -> 1, 3, 27
3 -> 1, 2
4 -> 5
5 -> 4
27 -> 1, 2
```

And finally after the third:

```
1 -> 2, 3, 27
2 -> 1, 3, 27
3 -> 1, 2, 27
4 -> 5
5 -> 4
27 -> 1, 2, 3
```

I currently have no solution for figuring out when the changing has stopped.

To get only one copy of each result you can remove all where the key is larger than any of the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `N` sets with around `M` elements each, the naive way (test every element of every set against every other) is `O(N^2 * M^2)` if duplication is rare.  If you actually have only `R << N*M` different elements, though, it's not as bad: you can stop testing once you find something, which happens after not around `N*M` comparisons but only `R`, so you are down to "only" `O(N*N*R)`.  But you don't have to test every set against every other if the sets actually live in only `L` groups, because you stop once you hit the right group.  So it's more like `O(N*L*R) + O(N*M)` (the second term is actually adding the elements to the groups once you find the right group to add to).

If you make a map from each element to the list of sets it contains--which you can do in `O(N*M)` time--then you can walk the tree of sets-per-element, visiting each distinct element at most approximately once (i.e. `R` of them), and for each one visiting every set that mentions it (which turns out to be about `N*M/R`) and adding all its elements (but just once!), which overall is `O(N*M)` time if you're careful not to add the same set multiple times.  (You'll need a wrapper for the sets so you can tell if you've already visited them.)  So that's faster, but if `L*R` is pretty small you may not care.

In Scala, the core of the map from elements to a tree would look something like

```
case class W(s: Set[Int]) { var visited: Boolean = false }
def tree(ss: Seq[Set[Int]]) = {
  var m = new collection.mutable.HashMap[Int, List[W]]
  ss.foreach{ s =>
    s.foreach{i =>
      m(i) = W(s) :: m.getOrElse(i, Nil)
    }
  }
}
```

and walking through the groups is more complex, but the basic idea is to keep a map of elements you've seen and not keep traversing if you hit one of those, and also to keep track of whether you've traversed a set by setting the flag in the W wrapper when you incorporate the elements.